# Hidden iframe or undetectable iframe by SEO

Tags: seo, iframe

I used Facebook Plugin Like Box in blogger. But SEO checker (seocentro.com, SINIUM) detect using iframe can cause indexing in Google.

Helplogger.blogspot.com use Iframe (adsense ad code converter and facebook like box plugin), but **SEO checkers do not detect as helplogger using iframe.**
How does it hidden from SEO checker tool? So means its **iframe content not affect any problems in SEO**.

I would appreciate if anyone can help, I have tried many times and searched on Google.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Online SEO checkers are notorious for giving outdated bad advice. Its common nowadays to use iframe on the site and in no way does Google or any other search engine punish for it. Iframes had a bad reputable over a decade ago because people were iframe everything unnecessary and abusing it.

Google own services require some iFrame! when embedding them to the page.

1. YouTube embed uses iframe.
2. Google maps embed uses iframe.
3. Google sheets embed uses iframe.

I recommend that you stop using such online tools and do some research using reputable sources no older than 2-3 years.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use Facebook Plugin Like Box that uses iframe. That's why I was very confused. Now I am clear for your help. Thank You.